# How to make a selected path to save an XML file?

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I have a function that can save a .xml file.

```
private void buttonSaveXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
     saveFile.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
     saveFile.Title = "Save a Xml File";
     saveFile.ShowDialog();
     if (saveFile.FileName != "")
     {
         FileStream fs = (FileStream)saveFile.OpenFile();
         dsVersions.WriteXml(fs);
     }
}
```

What do I add to make a specific path that I want to save it to?

Comment: You are giving the user control of the path.

Comment: Ya, I know, but is there a way that i can make a default path instead of Desktop? For example, if there is just a default place i want to save the xml document to instead of going to that path every time, i can just press buttonSaveXML_Click and that path will already be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the property InitialDirectory of SaveFileDialog form. For Example add this to your code:

```
saveFile.InitialDirectory = "C:\\MyXMLs\\";
```

You can see the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can control the [InitialDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx) so that the user will be "in the right place", but you cannot prevent them from switching directories with SaveFileDialog.

That way, they will be in your *default path* rather than e.g. on the Desktop.

```
saveFile.InitialDirectory = @"C:\My\Path" ;
```

Typically I will save the last directory that the user selected to save files to in application configuration and use the user's last directory as the InitialDirectory.

Comment: Ya i don't care if they switch directories i just need it to be there for a little while to test somethings.